# how to get multiple values of single radio button in php

Tags: php, radio-button

```
<input name="radio" type="radio" value="'.$row['fname'].','.$row['lname'].'">
```

this is my radio button I just want to get the value and have to display it in the two different text field.
I tried it but the value is showing in a single line with ,
like this:
Anand,Mor

Comment: `LIKE Anand,Mor` sounds db-related as in `LIKE - AND- MORE`?

Comment: now you went and destroyed Riggs' edit http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42118306/2

Comment: Why did you remove the code

Comment: @Fred-ii- Maybe there is more to come, lets give him a minute

Comment: @RiggsFolly either way the question IMHO is too broad. I'm out.

Comment: What's your input code and wha't your desired output?

Comment: <input name="radio" type="radio" value="'.$row['fname'].','.$row['lname'].'">

Comment: @RiggsFolly I think you're editing for nothing *lol* - he's only and more than likely going to undo it again.

Comment: and I want the values of radio button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value in the php or in the javascript and the **split** function with comma as separator.
php:

```
$result=split(",",$radio);
```

javascript

```
var result = value.split(",");
```

Comment: @SamuelTeixeria  getting error  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function split()

Comment: where do you put the split function ? Update the question and show what are you trying to do.

Comment: fixed that by using explode() :0